# How to handle an unchanging array in useEffect dependency array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, redux

I have a component like this. What I want is for the useEffect function to run anytime `myBoolean` changes.

I could accomplish this by setting the dependency array to `[myBoolean]`. But then I get a warning that I'm violating the `exhaustive-deps` rule, because I reference `myArray` inside the function. I don't want to violate that rule, so I set the dependency array to `[myBoolean, myArray]`.

But then I get an infinite loop. What's happening is the useEffect is triggered every time `myArray` changes, which is every time, because it turns out `myArray` comes from redux and is regenerated on every re-render. And even if the elements of the array are the same as they were before, React compares the array to its previous version using `===`, and it's not the same object, so it's not equal.

So what's the right way to do this? How can I run my code only when `myBoolean` changes, without violating the `exhaustive-deps` rule?

I have seen [this](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14476#issuecomment-471199055), but I'm still not sure what the solution in this situation is.

```js
const MyComponent = ({ myBoolean, myArray }) => {
  const [myString, setMyString] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    if(myBoolean) {
      setMyString(myArray[0]);
    }
  }, [myBoolean, myArray]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1**

If you always need the 1st item, extract it from the array, and use it as the dependency:

```
const MyComponent = ({ myBoolean, myArray }) => {
  const [myString, setMyString] = useState('');

  const item = myArray[0];

  useEffect(() => {
    if(myBoolean) {
      setMyString(item);
    }
  }, [myBoolean, item]);
}
```

**Solution 2**

If you don't want to react to `myArray` changes, set it as a ref with `useRef()`:

```
const MyComponent = ({ myBoolean, myArray }) => {
  const [myString, setMyString] = useState('');
  const arr = useRef(myArray);

  useEffect(() => { arr.current = myArray; }, [myArray]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if(myBoolean) {
      setMyString(arr.current);
    }
  }, [myBoolean]);
}
```

**Note:** redux shouldn't generate a new array, every time the state is updated, unless the array or it's items actually change. If a selector generates the array, read about memoized selectors ([reselect](https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect) is a good library for that).

Answer (score 0):

I have an idea about to save `previous props`. And then we will implement function compare `previous props` later. Compared value will be used to decide to handle function change in `useEffect` with `no dependency`.

**It will take up more computation and memory.** Just an idea.

Here is my example:

```
function usePrevious(value) {
    const ref = useRef();
    useEffect(() => {
        ref.current = value;
    });

    return ref.current;
}

function arrayEquals(a, b) {
    return Array.isArray(a) &&
        Array.isArray(b) &&
        a.length === b.length &&
        a.every((val, index) => val === b[index]);
}

const MyComponent = ({ myBoolean, myArray }) => {
    const [myString, setMyString] = useState('');
    const previousArray = usePrevious(myArray);
    const previousBoolean = usePrevious(myBoolean);

    const handleEffect = () => {
        console.log('child-useEffect-call-with custom compare');

        if(myBoolean) {
            setMyString(myArray[0]);
        }
    };

    //handle effect in custom solve
    useEffect(() => {
        //check change here
        const isEqual = arrayEquals(myArray, previousArray) && previousBoolean === myBoolean;

        if (!isEqual)
            handleEffect();
    });

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('child-useEffect-call with sallow compare');

        if(myBoolean) {
            setMyString(myArray[0]);
        }
    }, [myBoolean, myArray]);

    return myString;
}

const Any = () => {
    const [array, setArray] = useState(['1','2','3']);
    console.log('parent-render');

    //array is always changed
    // useEffect(() => {
    //     setInterval(() => {
    //         setArray(['1','2', Math.random()]);
    //     }, 2000);
    // }, []);


    //be fine. ref is not changed.
    // useEffect(() => {
    //     setInterval(() => {
    //         setArray(array);
    //     }, 2000);
    // }, []);


    //changed ref but value in array are not changed -> handle this case
    useEffect(() => {
        setInterval(() => {
            setArray(['1','2', '3']);
        }, 2000);
    }, []);

    return <div> <MyComponent myBoolean={true} myArray={array}/> </div>;
}
```